# Core Data Relationship and Parent Entitiy - Shopping Cart

Tags: core-data, parent-child, shopping-cart

I have right now (removing what's not important for this question) the following 3 entities. 
*(I don't have enough reputation to add images, sorry for the ascii)*

> `+------------+      +---------------+                  +----------------+
>       |  Product   |      |  CartProduct  |                  | Cart           |
>       +------------+      +---------------+                  +----------------+
>       | name       |      | quantity      |                  | total          |
>       | detail     |      | otherStuff    |                  | subTotal       |
>       | minimumBuy |      +---------------+                  | taxes          |
>       | price      |      | onCart        <----------+       | taxesPercentaje|
>       | thumb      |      +---------------+          |       +----------------+
>       +------------+                                 +-------> product        |
>                                                              +----------------+`

So, I have a *product* entity, with the info of the product, a *CartProduct* entity, that adds some info and the quantity of that product that we have on the cart (and is a child entity from *Product*) and finally the *cart*.

The specs say that I need to archive the carts when a purchase finishes, with the products as they are at the time of the sale, so, even if in the future the product price changes, I need the prices of the "*CartProducts*" to stay as they are.

I had until now *Products* and *CartProducts* related, but seeing that I need to save the state of the cart for future reference, I don't know what would be the best way to proceed.

**TL;DR**: Do I make a relationship between CartProducts and Products or do I just copy the data to the new entity at the moment of "adding products to the cart" knowing that I need to save the state of the product in the cart as it was when it was bought?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like either at least some of the data needs to be denormalized (i.e. copied), or you need to come up with a versioning solution, and have new versions of products when changes are made. The latter sounds too convoluted to me and not maintainable in the long run, so denormalizing sounds like the best solution.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I thought so, I'll be denormalizing t he products, I think is the easiest solution right now.